# What is the benefit of insertObject:atIndex: over replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject: on an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting

When replacing a value at some index with a new value within an NSMutableArray, the old value is held in memory.  The hack to fix is to initialize a new NSMutableArray before every loop.

Steps to Reproduce:

```
- (id) init{
    self.overlays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: [self.anotherArray count]];
}

- (void) someOtherMethod{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < self.anotherArray ; i++){
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
        [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 
                                                green:0 
                                                 blue:0 
                                                alpha:1]];
        [view setAlpha: .2];
        [self.overlays insertObject:view atIndex: i]
    }
}

- (void) main{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++){
        [myObject someOtherMethod];
    }
}
```

insertObject:atIndex effectively causes a memory leak, because it does not release the old value in the array at that index.

I filed a bug report and Apple responded:

insertObject:atIndex: is behaving as defined.  It is doing an insertion, not a replacement.  If you want replacement, you should instead use -replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:

How could the insertObject:atIndex: ever be of any benefit, as you always lose the reference to the old object at that index.

Is this simply to avoid fixing the issue as it meets old documentation definitions?

Comment: What did you think "insert" means?

Comment: The methods are different, hence the difference of name. Inserting an  object at an index is adding an object at a certain index and replacing an object at an index is basically taking an object at a certain index of an array, and replacing it with another object

Comment: Ah, I don't know what I was thinking

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The two methods do different things. Imagine the following array:

```
NSMutableArray *anArray = [@[ @1, @2, @3 ] mutableCopy];
```

If you *insert* an element at position `1`, like so:

```
[anArray insertObject:@4 atIndex:1];
```

The array becomes equal to `@[ @1, @4, @2, @3 ]`. The new element is inserted without removing another element.

If, instead, you *replace* the element at position `1`, like so:

```
[anArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@4];
```

You get `@[ @1, @4, @3 ]`. The previous object at that location is removed.

Answer (score 3):

`insertObject:atIndex` doesn't remove the old item, as you've already noted. Instead, it inserts the new item at the index you specify. After calling this method, the element count of the array is incremented by 1.

This is different from `replaceObjectAtIndex:withOjbect`, which is a replacement. The array's element count stays the same.

Insert does exactly that. Consider an array with 5 elements: if you call `[myArray insertObject:insertedObj atIndex:1];`, myArray instance now has 6 elements, with `insertedObj` inserted at the 1st index.